# Disconnected disks-Access denied, showing in explorer, but not showing in DISKPART and unable to remove them

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, hard-drive, command-line-interface

I have Virtual machine (terminal WIN2012), which seems to have under some users connected some OLD and NO longer connected disks (local or network drives), which are not accessible for anybody (even me as admin (access denied) I am sure, in this VM I dont have any other disks except C, no other volumes are present ... and I need to get rid of them, as they use a Drive letter, which is crucial for me to be mapped on specific disk drive letters.

- Computer configuration / disk management - after 1min. of loading it shows only volume C (+system reserved space with no drive letter)
- CMD with admin rights / DISKPART / command LIST DISK shows only 1 disk, LIST VOLUME shows those 2 disks only (C + sysem reserved with no letter)....whole DISKPART is initially loading almost a 1minute
- when I right click the "disk I want to remove" and select Properties, under Drivers I see Virtual HD ATA (which seems to be saying that it is something comming from my Virtual ATA driver) BUT :
- Device management shows only 1 VIRTUAL DISK device - Virtual HD ATA device, populating volumes shows : C: + System reserved
  The drives DO NOT EXIST, so no permissions are the problem, different users have different letters and different number of disks which I need to manually remove(some non, some 2disks, some 3,some4..., BUT HOW can I remove them?..anybody can help please?

I believe it must be written in some cached in REGISTRY or somewhere else, because DISKPART doesnt see it, but the system still counts with it (I see it, and running diskpart or other scanning takes incredibly too much time....

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: did you tries to uninstall it in the hardware manager?

Comment: you mean "unistalling the Virtual ATA device?....if yes, I am unsure what will happend - the Windows OS in this virtual machine  (C drive) shows the same Virtual ATA device with the same driver. If I uninstall it, I believe the C drive might be affected too (crash?, disk lost, etc?...or it will still be visible, fully working, but only using some "basic and native driver")

Comment: please show the output of the command: `echo list disk|diskpart` thanks

Comment: Hi, I have run it as admin, and I see only 1disk as online I mentioned before..see screenshot. https://photos.app.goo.gl/pJPGJqPeTriwa4bx7

Comment: i've found some similiar [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/996189/how-to-remove-phantom-drive-letters)

Comment: hi, thanks, unfortunately it did not work. Mountvol /R did basically nothing to my system, Mountvol R. /D made my server unresponsive and stuck ..I tried it 4x, always the same result....maybe the reason why it did not work for me is that I have it as virtual machine....any more ideas?

Comment: Once again an old dos possibilities  - `subst X: /D` where X: is the drive in case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the cause of this strange behaviour, which is unfortunately preventing from any kind of troubleshooting : phantom disks are simple created by App Google Team Drive, as each user has ability to map his Google drive to certain drive letter, those letters which are "taken by other logged in users" in the system are simply visible to other users too, however they are not accessible....I believe Google need to fix this behaviour, there is nothing we can do (at night, when all users are logged of, I see everything correctly, duing daytime when all users log in, I see 10 or more "phantom disks" which are simply just GDrive disks maped to other users...
thanks for helping me out.